# How can I show that $z=\frac{-i}{5}$ is contained in $S$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How can I show that $z=\frac{-i}{5}$ is contained in $S$?

Where,
$$ S= \left\{ z \in { \Bbb {C} } \space\bigg\vert\space\frac{1}{4} \left| \frac { (z+1) ^ {z+1} }{ (z-1) ^ {z-1} }  \right| \lt {1}\right\} $$

Since the $z$ is a complex number, can we prove this by using the following?
$$\begin{align}\frac{(z+1)^{z+1}}{(z-1)^{z-1}}&=\frac{ e^{(z+1)\log{(z+1)}}}{e^{(z-1)\log{(z-1)}}}\\ &=e^{(z+1)\log{(z+1)}-(z-1)\log{(z-1)}}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac { (z+1) ^ {z+1} }{ (z-1) ^ {z-1} } =(z^2-1)\left(    \frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)  ^z $$

let $z+1=re^{i \theta}$ so that $tan\theta=-1/5 $ and $z-1= re^{i(\pi-\theta)} $

so $$(z^2-1)\left(    \frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)  ^z =-\frac{26}{25} e^{i( 2 \theta - \pi  )(-i/\sqrt 5 )    }  = -\frac{26}{25} e^{\frac{ 2 \theta - \pi  }{\sqrt 5 }    }$$